# Keras fit() doesn't retrain the model on consecutive calls

Tags: python, deep-learning, theano, keras

After playing around with Keras, I realized that somehow models.fit() doesn't retrain the parameters after calling it again.

Below is my toy example. I called models.fit() 6 times, and at the fourth epoch I train it with a completely new dataset. What *should* happen is that the model should change at the fourth iteration so the fifth iteration should produce different scores as the third iteration. However, this is not what's happening.

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, border_mode='same', input_shape=(1, 199, 40)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(2))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

sgd = SGD(lr=0.1, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])

nb_epoch = 6

# I know you can add nb_epoch into the fit function, but please ignore that for now
for e in range(nb_epoch):
    if e ==3:
        # For the third epoch only, let's train the model 
        # on a completely new dataset
        model.fit(X_train1, y_train1, nb_epoch=1, batch_size=batch_size)
    else:
        model.fit(X_train2, y_train2, nb_epoch=1, batch_size=batch_size)
```

Results:

```
546/546 [==============================] - 11s - loss: 4.0249 - acc: 0.6996
Epoch 1/1
546/546 [==============================] - 11s - loss: 4.0443 - acc: 0.7491
Epoch 1/1
546/546 [==============================] - 11s - loss: 4.0443 - acc: 0.7491
Epoch 1/1
365/365 [==============================] - 7s - loss: 3.7977 - acc: 0.7644
Epoch 1/1
546/546 [==============================] - 11s - loss: 4.0443 - acc: 0.7491
Epoch 1/1
546/546 [==============================] - 11s - loss: 4.0443 - acc: 0.7491
```

It seems to be like calling model.fit after the second iteration has no effect at all on the model. Even if new data is given.

Any ideas on why this is happening? **I also tried train_on_batch and it produces the same results.**

Comment: Are you sure the problem is not with your data? You can compare calling fit once with 5 epochs and calling it 5 times with 1 epoch on the same data.

Comment: The 4th is in deed different from 3rd and 5th. Why do you expect "so the fifth iteration should produce different scores as the third iteration"? Your learning rate of 0.1 is very large for such network. One epoch probably has made it finished. Try smaller learning rate or some other data.